# What does "prescribed" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this passage from my reference book (Neal-S.-Widmer-Gregory-L.-Moss-Ronald-J.-Tocci-Digital-Systems-Pearson-Education-Limited-2017 - Page 28) and there is a word ***(in bold)*** which I haven't understand it yet.

> Circuits that can preserve exact voltages are much more complicated
>   than digital circuits that simply need to recognize a voltage in one
>   of two ranges. Digital circuits are designed to produce output
>   voltages that fall within the ***prescribed*** 0 and 1 voltage ranges such
>   as those defined. Likewise, digital circuits are
>   designed to respond predictably to input voltages that are within the
>   defined 0 and 1 ranges. What this means is that a digital circuit will
>   respond in the same way to all input voltages that fall within the
>   allowed 0 range; similarly, it will not distinguish between input
>   voltages that lie within the allowed 1 range

Comment: What does a dictionary say? Does a dictionary help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, roughly, *specified* or *required*. It has something of the sense of, "If you want *X* to be true, then you had better handle *Y* in the manner indicated."

It's often used in the context of standards or protocols.